# Return a variable to use as image src

Tags: javascript, php, image

I have a variable image that needs to display based on another form field so if the first form field says XYZ123 then the picture I need displayed will be in the server filesystem already and named XYZ123.jpg

I can't work out the syntax to put it in

```
<td colspan=3 align="center"><img src="pictures/thumbnails/logo-20170820013631.jpg" alt="Logo" border=1 height=150 width=150></img><br>Click to enlarge.</td>
```

This works fine if I use a static image name, but I need dynamic

I have a function that is called whenever the first field is changed

```
<div><b>EDIT CUSTOMER DETAILS</b><br><input type="text" name="key" onchange="changedReference(this.name);" placeholder="enter customer ID"></div>  //calls function

function changedReference(n)
{
    var ref = EL(n).value;
    var img = EL(n).value;
    if (ref == null || ref == "") return;

    var x = getXmlHttpRequest();
    if (x == null) {
        alert("Unable to get XmlHttpRequest");
        return;
    }

    var u = "card-get.php?reference=" + encodeURI(ref);

    x.open("GET", u, false);
    x.send();

    var t = x.responseText;
    if (t == null || t.indexOf('=') < 0) {
        alert("Unknown Customer ID [" + ref + "]");
        return;
    }

    var ra = t.split("\n");
    var lookup = new Object();
    for (var i = 0; i < ra.length; i++) {
        var pos = ra[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos < 0 || pos == 0) continue;

        var en = ra[i].substring(0, pos);
        var ev = ra[i].substring(pos + 1);

        if ((en == "dob" || en == "id1_expiry") && ev.length == 10 && ev.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
            ev = ev.substring(8, 10) + "/" + ev.substring(5, 7) + "/" + ev.substring(0, 4);
        }

        var e = EL(en);
        if (e != null) e.value = ev;
    }

}
```

so var img holds the value I need without the .jpg now I need it to display but am lost trying to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the image tag in your html an id like

```
<img id="changingImage" src="pictures/thumbnails/logo-20170820013631.jpg" />
```

Now you can change the image source to point to the filename inside your img variable...

```
document.getElementById('changingImage').src="pictures/thumbnails/"+img+".jpg";
```

Comment: Makes more sense than what I have been trying, where would I put the js?

Comment: You wrote  that var img already holds the value you need (without the .jpg), so you could add the code right after that line. But I guess var img needs to be updated based on the result of the XmlHttpRequest. I can't find that part of your code in the code you posted.

Comment: I thought var img would already hold the value you need (without the .jpg). What's inside that img variable when you do console.log(img);